# Test if array of week day names is sorted correctly?

Tags: ruby

So I'm trying to test if an array of week day names is sorted correctly regardless of where it starts so

```
[Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday] => true
[Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday] => true
[Monday, Thursday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Sunday, Friday, Saturday] => false
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
module Enumerable
  def sorted_by?
    each_cons(2).all? { |a, b| ((yield a) <=> (yield b)) <= 0 }
  end
end
```

and

```
correct_week_days = {
  :monday => 0,
  :tuesday => 1,
  :wednesday => 2,
  :thursday => 3,
  :friday => 4,
  :saturday => 5,
  :sunday => 6
}

test_week_days_array.sorted_by? { |k, v| correct_week_days[k.to_sym] }
```

This returns true on an array of unsorted weekday strings. I know this approach is flawed as it won't account for looping back around.

1. Is there a way to do this?
2. Why does it return true?

**Edit**

I should have provided an actual example for the data I'm testing

```
['monday', 'thursday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'sunday', 'friday', 'saturday']
```

This would be an example that should fail.

```
['wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday']
```

This would pass.

Comment: can you provide an example of `test_week_days_array`?

Comment: What about `%w[sunday monday]` or `%w[friday monday]` or `%w[thursday friday monday]`?

Comment: You should use Array#order if you want the most straightforward way, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dead simple, two-line algorithm that (optionally) works for inputs containing fewer than seven days.

Take the days:

```
days = %w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday)
# => ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
```

Double the array, so that it contains every possible valid sub-array:

```
days *= 2
# => ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
```

Given your input cases...

```
case1 = %w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday)
case2 = %w(thursday friday saturday sunday monday tuesday wednesday)
case3 = %w(monday thursday tuesday wednesday sunday friday saturday)
case4 = %w(wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday monday tuesday)
```

For each input case, see if there is any [slice of consecutive elements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) in the `days` array that matches your input:

```
days.each_cons(case1.length).include?(case1) # true
days.each_cons(case2.length).include?(case2) # true
days.each_cons(case3.length).include?(case3) # false
days.each_cons(case4.length).include?(case4) # true
```

All in all this is a two line solution:

```
def days_in_order?(days)
  search_list = %w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday) * 2
  search_list.each_cons(days.length).include?(days)
end
```

You'll need to handle the case where the input's capitalization doesn't match (`'monday'` vs `'Monday'`), but that's a trivial extension. If you want this to only accept input array which are seven days long, change `each_cons(days.length)` to `each_cons(7)`.

Answer (score 2):

What about some functional approach? Consider the code below (please note it could be written in more compact way, I left the big `if-than-else` for readability):

```
DAYS = [:monday, :tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday, :friday, :saturday, :sunday]

def days_sorted_ok?(weekdays)
  if weekdays.empty? || weekdays.count == 1
    # only one day, so it is sorted well
    return true
  else
    # true, if the next day (weekdays[1]) is the next on the DAYS list
    if weekdays[1] == DAYS[(DAYS.index(weekdays[0]) + 1) % DAYS.count]
      if weekdays.count == 2 
        # only two days in the table, so the whole thing is sorted well
        return true
      else
        # check if the tail of the array is sorted well
        days_sorted_ok?(weekdays[1..-1])
      end
    else
      # second element is not a next weekday
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

This is a recurring method. First, it checks if the array is empty or contains only one element. In this case it treats it as sorted in a good way. In the other case, it checks if the second element of the list is the next of the `DAYS` list (with modulo, to cycle the weekdays). If it is true, and the list contains only 2 elements, it means that it is sorted well. In the other case it will search **recursively** in the rest of the list.

Couple of tests are below:

```
days_sorted_ok? DAYS
#=> true
days_sorted_ok? [:tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday]
#=> true
days_sorted_ok? [:monday, :tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday, :friday, :sunday, :sunday]
#=> false
days_sorted_ok? [:monday, :tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday, :friday, :saturday, :sunday, :monday, :sunday]
#=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def same_order?(arr1, arr2)
  raise 'Not same array' unless arr1.sort == arr2.sort

  arr1.length.times do
    arr1 = arr1.rotate
    return true if arr1 == arr2
  end

  return false
end


correct_order = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
a = ['wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday']
b = ['monday', 'thursday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'sunday', 'friday', 'saturday']
p same_order?(correct_order, a) #=> true
p same_order?(correct_order, b) #=> false
```

Comment: I considered and rejected rotation because it cannot work if the array lengths do not match. However, if the array lengths must match, this is a good algorithm. I would simply suggest that you replace the guts with the simpler: `def same_order?(arr1, arr2); 0.upto(arr1.length).any? { |r| arr1.rotate(r) == arr2 }; end`

Comment: Thus the check at the beginning if they're the same. From his test cases it seems they're basically the same content.

Comment: I agree that `rotate` is a good choice.  Note you could use `(arr1-arr2).empty? && (arr2-arr1).empty?` rather than comparing sorted arrays.  That might be more efficient if there were millions of days per week. :-)

Answer (score 0):

My solution reorders the array under test and compares with a properly ordered array (along with a little data housekeeping)

```
def test a
  # deal with an array of symbols or strings
  a = a.map do |day| day.downcase.to_sym end
  # make sure we at least have a monday in the array so we don't get stuck
  if a.include? :monday
    # reorder array so that monday is the first element
    while a.first != :monday
      a << a.shift
    end 
  end 
  # does it match an ideal ordered array?
  a == [:monday, :tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday, :friday, :saturday, :sunday]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is to make use of the method [Array#rotate!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate-21) (or `rotate`).

I've assumed the array to be tested contains the names of the seven days of the week, capitalized, and nothing else. We are merely to check if the order is correct.

First, if the reader is not familiar with the construction of an array of strings using `%w`, here's an example:

```
%w{ Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday }
  #=> ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
       "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
```

**Code**

```
def dow_sorted?(arr)
  %w{ Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday }
    .rotate!(-arr.index('Monday')) == arr
end
```

**Examples**

```
dow_sorted? %w{ Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday }
  #=> true
dow_sorted? %w{ Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday }
  #=> true
dow_sorted? %w{ Monday Thursday Tuesday Wednesday Sunday Friday Saturday }
  #=> false
dow_sorted? %w{ Friday Saturday Sunday Monday Wednesday Tuesday Thursday }
  #=> false
```

**Explanation**

For the last example:

```
arr = %w{ Friday Saturday Sunday Monday Wednesday Tuesday Thursday }
  #=> ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday",
  #    "Wednesday", "Tuesday", "Thursday"] 

ord = %w{ Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday }
  #=> ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
  #    "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"] 

n = arr.index('Monday')
  #=> 3

a = ord.rotate(-3)
  #=> ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday",
  #    "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"] 

a == arr
  #=> false
```

Comment: I see @daremkd also used `Array#rotate`, but in a somewhat different way, so I will leave my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution just to have more algorithms collected together. In short - you find a position of monday and move it and all consecutive elements to the beginning of an array (in fact it's something like using `rotate`, but without `rotate`) and then compare with the correctly ordered list.

```
days = %w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday)

case1 = %w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday)
case2 = %w(thursday friday saturday sunday monday tuesday wednesday)
case3 = %w(monday thursday tuesday wednesday sunday friday saturday)
case4 = %w(wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday monday tuesday)

def days_in_order?(days)
  monday_index = days.index('monday')
  search_list = %w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday)
  search_list == days.slice(monday_index, days.size) | days[0...monday_index]
end

days_in_order?(case1) # true
days_in_order?(case2) # true
days_in_order?(case3) # false
days_in_order?(case4) # true
```

FYI, this algorithm is faster (~4s vs ~6s on my machine on 1000000 iterations for case3) than the one of @meagar, however his solution is easier to read and I think performance is not the goal in this case :-)

ps. I wrote `days.size` in `days.slice(monday_index, days.size)` instead of `days.size - monday_index` because it's not needed in fact as the goal is just to reach or exceed an array's size.